# SQLite blob data type retrieve result not same native android and phonegap

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, blob, phonegap-plugins

I developed 2 application for android. 1 of the application developed with phonegap another 1 is Android native. Both of the application have need to insert image. I used SQLite blob data type for image insert. Android Native application is not problem for me. Phonegap application retrieve result not same native . I thought error exists blob object create process or blob object insert to SQLite process.

 using **phonegap-1.4.1.js**.

**Base64 String convert to Blob object javascript function (Phonegap Application)**

```
function b64toBlob(b64Data){

contentType = 'image/png';
sliceSize = 512;


var BASE64_MARKER= ';base64,';
var base64Index = b64Data.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) + BASE64_MARKER.length;
var base64 = b64Data.substring(base64Index);  

var byteCharacters = b64Data;
var byteArrays = [];

for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    byteArrays.push(byteArray);

}

var BlobBuilder = window.BlobBuilder || 
                         window.WebKitBlobBuilder || 
                         window.MozBlobBuilder || 
                         window.MSBlobBuilder;
var bb = new BlobBuilder();

bb.append(byteArrays.buffer);

var blob = bb.getBlob(contentType); 

var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase(Mydb , ver, "", size);

db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql("Insert Into "+ DOPhotoTable +"( RefTranNo,Photo) values(?,?);",["C007", blob]);});
}
```

SQLite Debugger Application show the blob data **(Phonegap Application)**

[image: SQLite Debugger Application View]

SQLite Debugger Application show the blob data **(Native Application)**

[image: SQLite Debugger Application View]